# Email moodle password after change in Moodle 2.9

Tags: php, email, passwords, moodle

I have a Moodle 2.9 site and I would like to send the users an email after they change their password. Right now when they ask for a password change they get an email, but once they change it, they don't get a new one at least telling them that they changed it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i tried altering the moodle preferences, but didn't know exactly where to go, and the moodle.php on the lang folder don't have any options.

Answer (score 0):

create a function to send email after password update and call that function when \core\event\user_password_updated event triggered.